# Linq Except returning entire first set with custom comparer

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<MyObject>`, with `MyObject` like so

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string Item {get; set;};
  public string Country {get; set;};
  public int Phone {get; set;};
}
```

I wish to find objects that are in List A but not in List B, however the objects do not share reference so I want to compare by all the properties on the object. I have this which overrides `IEqualityComparer`

```
    public class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
    {
        private PropertyInfo[] publicInstanceProperties;

        public MyObjectComparer()
        {
            publicInstanceProperties = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        }

        public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in publicInstanceProperties)
            {
                if (property.CanRead && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && !property.GetValue(x).Equals(property.GetValue(y)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
        {
            long hashCodes = 0;
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(MyObject).GetProperties())
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(obj) ?? 0;
                hashCodes += value.GetHashCode();
            }

            return (int)(hashCodes % int.MaxValue);
        }
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
var comparer = new MyObjectComparer();
var result = listA.Except(listB, comparer);
```

However when I do this the result is always just the entire contents of `list A`, even if the properties of an object in list A and list B are identical. For instance, if I have

```
var listA = new List<MyObject>
{
  new MyObject
  {
    Item = "ItemName",
    Country = "Spain",
    Phone = 123456789
  },
  new MyObject
  {
    Item = "DifferentName",
    Country = "Portugal",
    Phone = 00000
  }
};

var listB = new List<MyObject>
{
  new MyObject
  {
    Item = "ItemName",
    Country = "Spain",
    Phone = 123456789
  }
};
```

Then my code returns the entire set of `listA`, even though it should only return the second item in `listA`. Please let me know if I am failing to understand how this works. Thank you.

Comment: Have you unit-tested your Comparer?

Comment: The comparer compares public properties. Your original declarations have private fields. Even if the private-ness is a typo (your code couldn't run at all if they were private), do double-check that you have properties (and if so, amend the question).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated the code, they are public. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I tried out the code exactly as you have it and it worked as expected. Maybe the problem is the way you are observing the results? Try `var result = listA.Except(listB, comparer).ToArray()`

Comment: What's with the `hashCodes % int.MaxValue`? Why not do `hashCodes ^= value.GetHashCode();`

Comment: Errors in your comparer: MyObject a = null; bool equal = MyComparer.Equals(a, a); Performance improvements: besides checking on null, check on ReferenceEquals. Consider checking on GetType: can ChildOfMyObject ever equal MyObject?

Comment: `var result = listA.Except(listB, comparer);` returns one item actually, but you can try to implement is using [`exclusive OR ^`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-), like it's recommended above

Comment: Also, _Notes of inheritors_ section in [`object.GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-inheritors) method tells you _You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable_  or _You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code_ Your `MyObject` is mutable, because of public setters, the state of instance can be changed without affecting hash code value

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjysVu)

I've run your code and it gives us the result as expected.

```
var comparer = new MyObjectComparer();
var result = listA.Except(listB, comparer).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Count: " + result.Count);     
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result[0]));
```

**Output**

```
Count: 1
{"Item":"DifferentName","Country":"Portugal","Phone":0}
```